# Getting Partial response from server using php

Tags: php

I am running a page with an Oracle query that will take more than one minute to execute.I am opening this page with the java script function window.open.During the query execution time the page is showing blank white page. Is there any method to show some status message instead of blank page.I used ob_flush and some other buffering function, but it is not working..

Comment: I think you can `window.open()` a status page which then `top.location.href = '';` forwards to the query page. The status page should normally be shown until the query page is finished.

Comment: if i run this url in normal page the same problem

Comment: Of course your query will take its time and it won't be displayed until its finished and you won't change this behavour. That's why I suggest you to split it into 2 seperate requests. One for the status message and one for the actual query.

Comment: @Christoph that is great thinking...:)

Answer (score 1):

Use AJAX to request the data from your server-side script. The page can then display any content you wish while the query procedes.

Comment: If you can use javascript, then what's stopping you from using AJAX?

Comment: AJAX is a client-side technology. The server can't reliably  distinguish between an AJAX call and any other. If you can implement a script on the server you can use AJAX.